# iOS/Swift: How to add one extension to multiple controllers?

Tags: swift

In a file called Extensions, I'm trying to add one extension to 2 View Controllers so I don't have to write the whole code twice.

```
import UIKit
extension TempConvertViewController {
// code
}
```

I need to use the exact same code for `LocationViewController`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: 
Thank you all for responding.

What I am trying to achieve is reuse the same keyboard/view code in 2 controllers as both contain textFields. The reason I've extended `TempConvertViewController` is because I have a variable (`activeTextField`) which won't be recognizable if I were to implement this in UIViewController.

If I put the code in a function, the `keyboardDidShow()` and `keyboardWillHide()` functions won't be recognized in the controller itself. I get the error: Use of unresolved identifier 'keyboardDidShow(notification:), Use of unresolved identifier 'keyboardWillHide(notification:)' 
See second part of the code below

Here is the extension of `TempConvertViewController`

```
extension TempConvertViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    @objc func keyboardDidShow(notification: Notification) {
        let notificationInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
        let keyboardSize = (notificationInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let yKeyboard = view.frame.size.height - keyboardSize.height
        let yTextFieldEditing: CGFloat! = activeTextField?.frame.origin.y

        if view.frame.origin.y >= 0 {

            //checking if textField is covered by keyboard
            if yTextFieldEditing > yKeyboard - 60 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations:{self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.origin.y -
                    (yTextFieldEditing! - (yKeyboard - 60)), width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)}, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: { self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)}, completion: nil)
    }
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        activeTextField = textField
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

`TempConvertViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Subscribe to Notifications
        let center: NotificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default;
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }
```

If I manage to include everything in one function, e.g. `keyboardViewManagement()`, can't I use a new extension for the other View Controller (`LocationChangeViewController`) like this:

```
extension LocationChangeViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

// calling the function
func keyboardViewManagement()

}
```

Thank you all again!

Comment: Another option is to put the code in a common base class instead of an extension.

Comment: @Xcoder has a pretty good answer - as does @rmaddy - but the bottom line is you need to give us more detail (specific code) to answer "What's best?". A *third* way to accomplish this is to (a) subclass `UIViewController` as, say, `VC1` (a base class) and then write an `extension VC1` - removing the "too broad" nature of writing an extension to `UIViewController`. In the end, it really gets down to your specific requirements, class hierarchy, even Xcode targets - none of which you've fully told us. But hopefully with three different route to handle this you'll find out the best route.

Comment: @Xcoder, thank you. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 5):

Use power of protocols, we are in swift after all

```
protocol Extendable: class {
    var editingTextField: UITextField? { get }
    func someFunc()
}

extension Extendable where Self: UIViewController {
    func someFunc() {
        // yor implementation
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var editingTextField: UITextField? {
        return activeTextField
    }
}
```

Comment: As for keyboard handling there are plenty ways to handle it in closures, for example https://github.com/ShengHuaWu/ObserveKeyboardNotifications

Answer (score 0):

Just write an extension of `UIViewController`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    //anything can go here

    func some() {
    }
}
```

Then in your view controller:

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    some()
}
```

Comment: I commented on how this may be too broad. An extension to `UIViewController` will work, but if certain code - depending on project/app size, how many developers are on the team, how much you *really* want to expose such a function to **every** view controller... well, this may be using a "broader brush" than you really wish to.

Comment: I take your point, which makes sense. UIViewController is not the way to go in my case. I will look into other options and see what fits the project. Thank you.